# Finite dimensional subspace of a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I have a proof for showing that a subspace of finite dimensional vector space if finite dimensional and I'm not sure if it works. If $W$ is a subspace of the vector space $V$, dim(V)=n and we assume dim(W) is infinite. $V$ has to contain the spanning set of $W$ for $W$ to be a subspace of $V$, however if dim(W) is infinite it doesn't have a finite spanning set. This means $V$ doesn't have a finite spanning set either, contradicting that dim(V)=n because n is finite. Does this proof work?

Comment: The proof looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think a more useful proof is to show that if $\dim V =n$, then any collection of $n+1$ vectors in $V$ is linearly dependent. In particular, $W$ can contain at most
$n$ linearly independent vectors and so we have $\dim W \le \dim V$.

Answer (score 0):

It is more or less what you are saying, but you could think about the inclusion as an injective homomorphism $\iota: W\rightarrow V$. Then $\dim W\leq \dim V$.